# How structure pointer will assigned to zero with out having pointee address and find sizeof structure in below code?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, gnu

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct test 
{
    int a;
    char b;
    int c;
};
int main()
{
    struct test *ptr = (struct test *)0;  
    ptr++;
    fprintf(stderr, "by pointer = %zd\n", (size_t) ptr);
    fprintf(stderr, "by sizeof = %zd\n", sizeof(struct test));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: If a pointer is assigned to zero then there is no pointee

Comment: it is always best to cast a pointer to `uintptr_t`, which is guaranteed to be the size of a pointer. `size_t` is not guaranteed to fit it

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour on incrementing `ptr` in your case is *undefined*.

Note that `(size_t)ptr` is *implementation defined*. It is always valid to cast a pointer to size_t, however if the result cannot be represented by type size_t, the behavior is undefined.

The C standard allows you to set a pointer to 0, but pointer arithmetic is only valid in arrays, with the exception that you are allowed to point one past the end of an array or one past the address of a scalar.

Note that the correct format specifier for a `sizeof` type is `%zu` - else you have the potential for even more *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: but this code is working i am not getting that point ptr++ ? its giving correct sizeof struct

Comment: That's the nature of undefined behaviour. It might appear to work, on other days the compiler might eat your cat.

Comment: Conversion from pointers to integer is implementation-defined.

Comment: `size_t` ain't an `int`.

Comment: @Bathsheba size_t is an integer. Conversion between *integers*.

Comment: `size_t` is an `unsigned` type.

Comment: @2501: You're correct on the cast to size_t. I've amended.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call it always valid, as if the value cannot be represented, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: it is always best to cast a pointer to `uintptr_t`, which is guaranteed to be the size of a pointer.